# How to update the $account object in Drupal 8 hook_user_login

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to use the hook_user_login to update the $account as such that one of the roles is removed. $account is a protected object and it allows me to get (`$account->getRoles();`) the roles array but not allowing me to set it. Can anyone advise if there is a way to edit the `$account` roles before processing the user login request?

```
function restrict_by_ip_user_login($account) {

  //Edit account roles here before proceeding


  $login_firewall = \Drupal::service('restrict_by_ip.login_firewall');
  $login_firewall->execute($account);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeRole` method, something like the following snippet could help you

```
function restrict_by_ip_user_login($account) {

  $user = user_load_by_name($account->name);
    if ($user) {
      $user-> removeRole('MACHINE_NAME_OF_ROLE');
      $user->save();

    }

  $login_firewall = \Drupal::service('restrict_by_ip.login_firewall');
  $login_firewall->execute($account);
}
```

Comment: but this will remove the user role permanently in the database, which is not ideal. I want a specific role to be not available in the current session when logining outside the range of whitelist IP addresses.

Comment: Basically I am trying to use the restrict role by IP `feature of restrict_by_ip` however its not working as expected even with the patches applied. https://www.drupal.org/node/2651106#comment-10958295

Comment: @Saber you did not mention it. btw,  my suggestion is, duplicate the roles,
and assign/remove them base on the user ip.

something like this,  writer_role, write_role_restricted,  when  user is loged in check his/her role, if it's out of IP, drop . writer_role and add restricted one. if it's on the ip range drop  restricted and add the normal role.

Comment: @Saber , it has not my requirement yet. but it's easy to implement.